# JQuery replace entire DIV using .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-load

I want to refresh a `<div>` on the close of a jQuery UI Modal Dialog.

My code is:

```js
var dialog = jQuery('#divPopup').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 450,
    width: 650,
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery('#divPopup').dialog('destroy').remove();
        jQuery("#bodyId").load("http://www.xyz.com/ #bodyId");
    }
});
```

But instead of replacing it, that adds the new `<div>` inside the old `<div>`:

```html
<div id="bodyId">
    <div id="bodyId">
        New Response
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to replace old div `bodyId` with new div `bodyId`.

Comment: Are you sure your server dide script `"http://www.xyz.com/#bodyId"` does not include a `<div id="bodyId">` in its output?

Comment: @techfoobar there is a space before `#bodyId`. Have a look at [`.load()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/), chapter "Loading Page Fragments".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
jQuery("#bodyId").load("http://www.xyz.com/ #bodyId");
```

... with this:

```
jQuery("#bodyId").load("http://www.xyz.com/ #bodyId > *");
```

This works because you can use any selector after the URL. By using `#bodyId > *` instead of just `#bodyId`, you match everything that is *inside* the div, instead of the div itself.

You need this because `.load()` will not replace an element; it will *append* the result of the AJAX call to the element.

Alternatively, you could use `.get()` to load the data and manually perform the selection, like so:

```
$.get('http://www.xyz.com/', function(data) {
    var newContent = $(data).find('#bodyId').children();
    $('#bodyId').empty().append(newContent);
});
```

Examples of both methods are online here: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/47qz3/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use jquery.get.

```
$.get('http://www.xyz.com/', function(data) {
  $('#bodyId').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score -4):

you may be use this code like

```
$('#bodyID').remove();
$('#bodyID').load();
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. The first line would remove the `div` from the DOM tree, which means the jQuery selection on the second line won't have a match.